# Did Rambam wear "Rambam tzitzit," etc

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, tzitzis, arizal

Some rabbis have invented their own methods for tying tzitzit, depending on their interpretation of the halachah. For instance, Maimonides had his own method for tying tzitzit that he passed onto the Yemenites, and the Ben Ish Chai and the Arizal also had their own methods. You can see each method here: [Rambam](http://www.hasofer.com/html/img/TzitzitRambam.jpg) - [Ben Ish Chai](http://www.tallit-shop.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Tzitzit-Sephardic-01.jpg) - [Arizal](http://www.hasofer.com/html/img/TzitzitChasidHuliot.jpg)

But my question is this: did these rabbis tie their own tzitzit in the methods they had come up with, or did they still follow the common practice of their ancestors (like maybe Rambam and Ben Ish Chai wore Sephardi tzitzit and the Arizal had his tied Ashkenazi)?

Comment: Why do you think any of those rabbis invented their methods from scratch?

Comment: I am confused by this question,are you talking about techeles or just white?

Comment: Just white. Techelet was not an option in the times of the Rambam, Ben Ish Chai, and Arizal.

Comment: He held that one needs at least 7 chulays and max 13,a chulaya consists of 3 wrappings ,some hold to tye a special knot like the Yeminites,while others just make a regular knot

Comment: Is this Jews, or Judaism?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31511/9629

Comment: ...why wouldn't they? If they thought that their method was correct, why would they do something else?

Comment: @Shokhet The Chofetz Chaim ruled that tzitzis should be worn out, but he did not do so himself. Halacha is more complex than that.

Comment: I did not know that about the Chofetz Chaim. (I mean, I'm pretty sure that he ruled, in Mishnah Berurah, to wear them out "unless the *goyim* will mock you" or something like that. Perhaps he considered his time and place to fall under that category?) ...but perhaps your underlying assumptions should be added to the question with an [edit]. I don't see a very strong case here without adding a more substantive basis for your query.